# Declaring a variable-length array of fixed-length strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax

I need an array of strings. The length of a string is known at compile-time and it is crucial that each string takes up this much space. The number of strings on the other hand is only known at runtime. What is the syntax for this?

`char* data[STRLENGTH]` is incorrect syntax. `char** data` mostly works but then `sizeof(data[0])` is wrong -- it should be equal to `STRLENGTH`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Daniel is correct, but this code can confuse people who read it - it's not something you usually do. To make it more understandable, I suggest you do it in two steps:

```
typedef char fixed_string[STRLENGTH];
fixed_string *data;
```

Comment: It's not *that* confusing; pointers to arrays aren't that much more complicated than pointers to other types.  It's just that the precedence of `[]` over `*` requires explicit grouping.

Comment: My first instinct when I see something like char (*data) is to find the function pointer. Anyway, there's hardly any downside to defining an intermediate type (you'll pass it by reference and not by value without expecting it, but that's not always an issue)

Comment: This also works with malloc, while newer C++ compilers won't accept a cast like `(char*[12])`

Answer (score 7):

```
char (*data)[LEN];                   // where LEN is known at compile time
...
data = malloc(sizeof *data * rows);  // where rows is determined at run time
...
strcpy(data[i], some_name);
...
printf("name = %s\n", data[i]);
...
free(data);
```

Note that `data` is a pointer type, not an array type (`data` is a pointer to a `LEN`-element array of `char`).  The `malloc` call will dynamically allocate enough memory to hold `rows` arrays of length `LEN`.  Each `data[i]` will be type `char [LEN]`.

Answer (score 6):

```
char* data[STRLENGTH]
```

declares an array of `STRLENTGH` pointers to `char`. To declare a pointer to array of `STRLENGTH` `char`s, use

```
char (*data)[STRLENGTH]
```

Comment: Though one thing to be mindful of is if Erik passes this across function boundaries, he should not use `sizeof` to get the size of the string because of the pointer-decaying.

Comment: `data` is a pointer, so there's no decay issue.  `data[i]`, OTOH, is an array expression, and that *would* decay to a pointer if passed to a function.